# Why SQL server does not have column-level locking?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, locking

As far as i know, the lowest level locking is row-level

However i don't see the reason why it can not have column level locking

Assume that 2 queries simultaneously updates 2 different columns.

So why it can not happen? Why each update has to lock at least row level?

This behavior tells me that i should split table into smaller tables so less row level locking would happen

Am i incorrect?

Comment: I don't know a RDBMS that has column level locking.

Comment: @vercelli i dont know either. but i wonder the reason behind it.

Comment: Too many resources to do that. Actually you should take a look at "In Memory OLTP for SQL Server (2014 and 2016). It has optimistic concurrency locks (I'm no expert there). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx

Comment: Or this: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introducing-sql-server-in-memory-oltp/

Comment: @vercelli i see. however it requires SQL server 2016 and i still afraid that data loss may happen :D though Memory OLTP looks very promising. i guess i can turn trivial tables into memory tables if i upgrade to SQL 2016. however i still wonder why not column-level lock

Comment: It's available since 2014.

Comment: @vercelli yes but so strict restrictions. also i see that web edition does not support it

Comment: Yes, vertical partitioning (splitting into several tables with fewer columns each) is a legitimate strategy. It is important to maintain logical consistency. For example, splitting and address with City in one table and Postcode in another would be .. um .. sub-optimal.

Answer (score 3):

This feature could exist. It would consume resources and complicate the architecture. So it's a trade-off that had to be made.

For the same reason some databases go in the opposite direction: They lock on the page or table level. [MongoDB even has a global write lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456671/to-what-level-does-mongodb-lock-on-writes-or-what-does-it-mean-by-per-connec) for the entire database! This surely makes some physical implementation concerns much easier.

SQL Server's locking model already is quite sophisticated and, in my experience, addresses practical scenarios very well. I'm not sure column level locking would make it a better product (even if the developer time were free for Microsoft).

Comment: so it is totally about decisional thing rather than technical possibility. if they wanted, they could have made it right?

Comment: Correct. An RDMS has tons of architectural choices. SQL Server seems to be one of the most pristine architectures that I see in the database space.

Answer (score 0):

The few times I thought column level locking was needed, I came to the realization later on that it was a bad schema design.  The columns needing to be locked should have been placed in a separate table.

Answer (score -3):

Because even row-level locking is "fake" to some extent, no pun intended - the smallest thing you can *really* lock is a block on the underlying filesystem, which is the atomic unit of I/O, which may be anywhere from 512 bytes to 8k usually. So since you need to serialize at that level anyway, a column lock doesn't give you anything a row lock wouldn't concurrency and performance-wise.

Comment: A filesystem block can be larger than one row. It's a physical unit. A row lock does not lock any page necessarily (at least not using a high lock level).

Comment: Sure but there is no such thing as simultaneous write to a block. You would need 2 disk heads for a start! So what advantage does individually locking 2 columns with a row give you? None, but a lot of extra complexity and wasted memory.

Comment: Two transactions could write to the same row and coexist. There will not be a physical update at the same time but at least the two trans do not conflict. Less blocking/deadlocking. It's the same advantage that row locking has (as opposed to table or page locking).

Comment: @Gaius how about SSD? they dont have any heads

Comment: Even pages of memory cannot be updated simultaneously - that is just not how hardware actually, physically works. You have to serialize access anyway.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG ah, i see you are just trolling - well played

Comment: "a column lock doesn't give you anything a row lock wouldn't concurrency and performance-wise.". It could allow you to update the values in a column in a large table without blocking other queries that read different columns. All the physical stuff is irrelevant. Locks are logical. Latches take care of ensuring that only one process can write to a page in SQL Server, unlike locks these are not coupled to transaction lifetime. There is no prohibition on different processes acquiring row locks and writing to rows on the same page that all get written out at the same time....

Comment: ...The physical hardware write is not synchronous with the logical operation. It happens later eg during a checkpoint. The only thing that needs to happen on the file system before the transaction commits is the write ahead logging.

Comment: Writers don't block readers in any semi-modern database, so you don't know what you're talking about

Comment: They do by default in SQL Server. The snapshot isolation levels are not the default. The same applies to two writers though. A column level lock could allow one transaction to update column A and another column B in the same row without blocking each other. Exclusive locks will be held to the end of the transaction which is significantly longer than a latch to update the page and release it.

Comment: Would mean that the snapshot isolation architecture would have to change though if the unit of versioning was the row and column not just the row.

Comment: "Writers don't block readers in any semi-modern database". This phrase clearly shows you have little familiarity with how things work in SQL Server. I imagine you're trying to apply concepts from other databases built from the ground up using MVCC. In which case probably best you stay out of questions about locking in SQL Server until you understand how it works in that product TBH.

Comment: Question is tagged 2014 and snapshot isolation level was introduced in 2005. Clearly you lack the long experience I have in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes clearly I know nothing about SQL Server. That must be the problem here. Or alternatively it might be that I'm well aware of that and also aware that this is not the only isolation level available or even the default isolation level.